# Django Rest comparar id do 'setor' do usuário com id do 'setor' da publicação

Tags: python, api, django, django-rest-framework

Bom, estou mexendo com uma API e quero que ela retorne o conteúdo somente quando o setor do usuário for igual ao setor da publicação

API das publicações:

[image]

O usuário tem um campo sector também igual a este, e
já estou conseguindo pegar o id do setor do usuário atual, porém não consigo pegar o id do setor da publicação para testar!

views.py

```
class PostDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
queryset = Post.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    user_sector = None
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_sector = self.request.user.sector.id

        if user_sector is ...:
            return queryset
```

lembrando que eu quero retornar a queryset toda vez que o setor de alguma publicação for igual ao setor do usuário logado!! me ajudem nessa

Comment: Tenta usar o self.get_object() que ele retorna o objeto da view de detalhes atual, assim vai poder fazer: post.sector e assim fazer a verificação com o do user.

Comment: Preciso passar o setor como parâmetro ?

Comment: deu esse erro agora 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Comment: Não necessariamente.. Tira o quetyset de dentro do get_queryset.. Tenta usando o get_object dentro do get_queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, encontrei a solução de um jeito diferente, fiz um filtro nos objetos pelo id do setor, e ficou assim:

ps: também botei um condição OR pra pesquisar pelo setor 'Geral', que deve aparecer para todos os usuários

```
from django.db.models import Q 

class PostListAPIView(ListAPIView):
queryset = Post.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    user_sector = None
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_sector = self.request.user.sector.id
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(
                        Q(sector__id=user_sector) |
                        Q(sector__name='Geral')
                        ).distinct()   
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

Ai ta mais para uma questão de permissionamento, pelo que entendi. Sendo assim quando o setor da publicação for diferente do setor do usuário você quer recusar esse request (e provavelmente retornar uma mensagem de erro).

Eu implementaria da seguinte forma:

```
class PostDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
 queryset = Post.objects.all()
 serializer_class = PostSerializer
 permission_classes = (ClasseVerificacao)
```

Então você precisa implementar a suca "**ClasseVerificacao**"

```
# CLASSES PARA CONTROLE DE PERMISSIONS
class ClasseVerificacao(permissions.BasePermission):
  message = 'Permissão negada, seu setor não é o mesmo do objeto'

  def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return self.request.user.sector == obj.sector
```

Perceba que essa parte retorna True quando o sector do usuario é igual ao sector do objeto. Quando a função retorna True ele responde o request, caso a função retorne False ele responde a request com a **message** que você escolheu.

> return self.request.user.sector == obj.sector

Bem fica "complicado" fazer o código exatamente para o seu problema, aí tem um exemplo que já deve te ajudar. E lembre de olhar a documentação.